# Why does partitioning the rodents change the probability?

Tags: probability

from Casella and Berger's text:

> Two litters of a particular rodent species have been born, one with
>   two brown-haired and one gray-haired (litter 1), and the other with
>   three brown-haired and two grayhaired (litter 2). We select a litter
>   at random and then select an offspring at random from the selected
>   litter. What is the probability that the animal chosen is
>   brown-haired?

The answer is:

> P(Brown Hair)
>   = P(Brown Hair|Litter 1)P(Litter 1) + P(Brown Hair|Litter 2)P(Litter 2) = $\frac {19} {30}$

My answer was simply $\frac {5} {8}$, with 5 brown animals out of 8 total animals.

I feel like this is a common mistake. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your answer would be correct if you were choosing one of animals uniformly at random, but you are not.  You are choosing one litter uniformly at random and then choosing from that litter.  Very different.

Comment: Could you explain the difference intuitively?

Comment: I posted something below, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer would be correct if you were choosing one of animals uniformly at random, but you are not.  You are choosing one litter uniformly at random and then choosing from that litter.  Very different.

To illustrate the point, suppose litter $1$ had one brown haired animal only, and that litter $2$ had ten gray animals.  Then the probability of choosing the brown animal is $\frac 12$ since you are guaranteed to get that one if you choose litter $1$, and you are guaranteed to get a gray one if you choose litter $2$.  Of course if you chose uniformly from all the animals the answer would be $\frac 1{11}$.

A standard problem along these lines:  You have $100$ marbles, $50$ each of black and white.  You get to apportion the marbles between the two urns in any manner you like (no need to have $50$ in each, though let's say that each urn must contain at least one marble).  I will then choose an urn at random and draw a marble from that urn at random.  Supposing you prefer that I choose a black one...how should you apportion the marbles?

The answer, along the same lines as my rodent example, is to place one black marble in urn $1$ and the other $99$ in urn $2$.  That comes to nearly a $\frac 34$ chance that I'll choose black.  (to be exact it is $\frac 12\times 1+\frac 12\times \frac {49}{99}=.\overline {74}$)

Comment: Now that you have explained it, it is clear that that is the optimal marble partition, but does the proof involve brute force?

Comment: Try it!  It's not too bad.  Suppose you assign $b$ black and $w$ white to urn $1$, and compute the probability.  Now optimize.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984130/how-can-one-maximise-a-probability) is a (partially worked) version of the calculation.